# Performance drop in MongoDB writes after migrating from 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: mongodb

After migrating from MongoDB 2.4 to 2.6 we have observed a significant drop in write operations performance. This is probably due to [this change introduced in 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#new-write-operation-protocol), which makes write operations synchronous.

Is there any way of configuring MongoDB 2.6 to behave as 2.4 with regards to the write operations in order to get a similar performance? Looking to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719211/why-are-inserts-slow-in-the-2-6-mongodb-shell-compared-to-previous-versions), a "legacy" mode is mentioned, but it is not fully clear if that is a feature of the Mongo shell or a feature of MongoDB itself.

In addition, I have been reading about the [bulk insert operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/bulk-write-operations/), but I'm not sure if it could help in this case. Taking into account our application logic, we cannot "package" several writes. Would it be of any help using this kind of operations to improve write performance in the case of mono-write bulks (i.e. a bulk operation comprising only one write operation)?

Comment: I'm curious if you'd get more answers for this over at dba.stackexchange, since this isn't related to coding.

Comment: I opted for posting at SOF after looking similar questions about MongoDB performance here (like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719211/why-are-inserts-slow-in-the-2-6-mongodb-shell-compared-to-previous-versions). However, if people think it would be better to move the question to dba.stackexchange, no problem on that.

Comment: The new write commands in MongoDB 2.6 are not about making all writes synchronous .. I think you've conflated shell behaviour with driver behaviour ;-). If you have a performance issue, you need to post more information (e.g. `mongod` log files and `mongostat` output) to help someone interpret what is happening. An open ended discussion around performance would also likely be better suited to the [mongodb-user forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user) than StackExchange.

Comment: You should also include some information on your deployment topology (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster) and specific driver/server versions before and after the upgrade (i.e. MongoDB 2.4.x => MongoDB 2.6.x).

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is partially correct. In Mongo 2.6 they introduced concept of writeconcerns.

With the help of this feature you can decide how durable you want to make your write operation. various levels are present with tradeoffs between performance and security.

**writeconcern=strict** 
  
This is highest secure level which will write on all replicas and then only will commit.

**writeconcern=safe** 
 This is 2nd highest secure which will write on (replicas/2)+1 replicas to ensure write is safe before commit.

**writeconcern=normal** 
This is similar to safe level but value is present in config file i.e. user defined value which is generally 1 or quorum

**writeconcern=none** 
 This is lowest level of security which will make asynchronous write.

With the help of writeconcern=normal with value as 1 or if you are fine with write security then writeconcern=none will give you best performance as compared to writeconcern=safe or strict which are used by default.

As you mentioned bulk writes are for huge data and not for single data. beats the whole idea of bulk writes. One more way you can try is(if possible), write all writes to a buffer and then write using bulk insert at the end.